# Julia live plot with atom

Tags: plot, julia

what is the easiest way to plot values from example for loop to same plot window? 
I try Plots, but atom doesn't open any plot windows. When I try to do same in Julia terminal everything is fine.  Example:

```
using Plots
plot(Plots.fakedata(50,5),w=3)
```

I have socket connection from other program and I want to plot line of the values what I get. Or is this possible to do with PyPlot?

Comment: Try using the `plotlyjs` Plots backend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `gui()` to display the plot window.

In the REPL, objects that are returned are displayed. That's why anything without a `;` gets displayed (also matrices, vectors, etc.). When you go to a script, that's no longer true (which is why you don't need to use `;`). In Atom it's reading it in script mode, so you have to manually display things via `display(obj)`, or if using plots you can just use `gui()`.

To display things in the same plot window, you simply set reuse=true when setting the backend, i.e.

```
gr(reuse=true)
```

Note you can also add `show=true` to make it automatically show when plots are made instead of having to call `gui()`.

Then to do live plotting, just push the new values into the plot. The full code looks like this:

```
using Plots
gr(reuse=true)
p =plot([0;.1],[0;.2])
gui()
for i=2:10
  push!(p,i*.1,randn())
  gui()
  sleep(.1) # To slow things down for show.
end
```

This answer should work with any backend. Note I switched to [GR.jl](https://github.com/jheinen/GR.jl) since [it tends to be faster](https://juliaplots.github.io/backends/)

Comment: Yes, now I have plot window! But problem is still plotting live values. If plot variables one by one, it will plot dots( if I set marker="o") not a line. If I make array and push! the new value to array and then plot it, it will only plot many lines on top of each other. Is there way to plot live value like line? Or is this a another question?

Comment: @pinq- I edited to include a way to incrementally add to a line. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: That is kind of right. I did the same, but added for loop, like: "for i=1:15;push!(p,i);gui();end;" I had to add "gui()" to display the new line. Problem is that it is really slow. Maybe because it opens/update the window every time.

Comment: @pinq- If you need it to be faster, don't use PyPlot. matplotlib is quite slow. Instead switch to the GR backend. I edited the code to use GR.

Comment: This is much better and faster! Just don't close the plot window, then it's good. If you close it, it will not show anything and you have to restart julia in atom. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This is a GR problem. I already pinged jheinen on his [Gitter](https://gitter.im/jheinen/GR.jl?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge).

Comment: @pinq- If you've closed GR window, I think you can reset things back to normal by calling GR.emeregencyclosegks()